# The background image doesn't load on my phone but does for others

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

cocos2d: Couldn't create texture for file:OV_map_2560x2560.png in CCTextureCache
Any idea why this happens to 2 of my phones and none of my friends' phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every device is capable of loading textures that are larger than 2048x2048.

Maximum texture sizes:

**1024x1024**

- iPhone (original)
- iPhone 3G

**2048x2048**

- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPad (original)

**4096x4096**

- iPhone 4S and newer
- iPad 2 and newer

Answer (score 0):

Would I be right in assuming that `OV_map_2560x2560.png` is a 6 megapixel image? That would need 18 MB of storage to display.

Make the image smaller, and you'll have a better chance of getting it to appear on mobile devices.